# About topological group and a connected component

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

If $G$ is a toplogical group and $H$ is a connected component of $G$ containing the identity $e$ of $G$, then how can we show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

I get that $xHx^{-1}$ is a connected component of $G$. Now I need to know how to show that $H \subseteq xHx^{-1}$.  Because then $H= xHx^{-1}$ due to the fact that $H$ is maximal connected. So $H$ is normal...
So how can I show that $H \subseteq xHx^{-1}$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sketch of Proof:** A subgroup $H$ is normal if $gHg^{-1} \subset H$ for all $g \in G$.  Note, however, that the map $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is continuous. So, $gHg^{-1}$ must be a connected component of $G$ that contains $e$.

---

Actually, we never showed that $H$ is necessarily a subgroup of $G$.  To that end: consider any $g\in H$.

> **Claim:** for any $g \in H$, $gH = H$.  Similarly, $Hg = H$.

**Proof:**
Note that the map
$$
x \mapsto gx
$$
is a homeomorphism, so $gH$ is a connected component.  Moreover, $gH$ contains $ge = g$.  So, $gH$ is a connected set with $gH \cap H \neq \emptyset$.  It follows that $gH \subset H$, so that $gH = H$.  $\square$

> **Claim:** The map $\phi(x) = x^{-1}$ satisfies $\phi(H) = H$.

Proof: same argument as above, noting that $\phi(H)$ is a connected component containing $e$.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: How to show gHg* is contained in  H where g* is inverse of g .

Comment: That's what the second part of the hint is for.  What do you know about continuous maps?  What's special about connected components?

Comment: This map is homomorphism so gHg* is  connected .

Comment: Not only is $gHg^*$ connected, it also contains the identity element

Comment: Yes it contain e because H has e so geg*= gg* = e. Then i take any gxg* from gHg* . Now e= gyg* for some y in H.  Then now i how to show gxg* is in H.???

Comment: Nothing after your first sentence makes any sense to me, I'm sorry to say.  I think you will find it useful to consider the following: $gHg^*$ *is a connected set which contains $e$*.

Comment: I am enable to do this. I now we get then gHg* = H but how... Don't able to do. Please help.....

Comment: You are unable to consider a statement?  That's unfortunate.  Let me ask you this: what exactly does the phrase "$H$ is maximal connected" (as you put it) mean?

Comment: H is maximal connected. It means that if H is contained in  any connected set M   then  then M=H  ie there is no other conncted set containing H.....

Comment: Right! And there's an important consequence: if $M$ is connected and $M \cap H$ is non-empty, then $M \subset H$.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: From this we get  that both  gH g* and H have  e  and now H is maximal and gHg*  is connected  having non empty intersection. so gHg* is contained in H .  Hence H is normal...

Comment: @samankumar and there it is! Yes, that's it.

Comment: Thanks...for great explanation......

Comment: Now the map gxg* is homomorphism so can i say that gHg* is also a maximal connected. ????? So xHx* is contained in H implies that xHx* =H.  is this true?????

Comment: @samankumar it's a **homeomorphism**, i.e. an continuous map with a continuous inverse.  So, $H$ is a maximal connected subset implies that $xHx^*$ is a maximal connected subset.  So indeed, $xHx^* \subset H \implies xHx^* = H$.

Comment: In addition, H is closed since cl H is connected, whence cl H subset   H.